# Background image not responsive when viewed on mobile or iPad

Tags: android, html, css, mobile, background

I am having an issue with the background image for my site.

When re-sizing in the browser (chrome) it responds how it should, however when I upload it to my server and open the site from my mobile device, it does not re-size. The image just stays the original size and is zoomed into one area of the  image.

Can anyone help please?

Here is the code:

```
html{
    background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for small devices use following property

html{background-size: 100% auto;}

Comment: I still can't get it working, been looking all over google and no one seems to have an answer for it.